# How to avoid points instancing at specific areas

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I am trying to spawn points only on the faces outside the Empty and avoid spawning them inside the area where the empty sphere is colliding.

[image]

Nothing fancy in the geonodes as of now. I tried using the geometry proximity node but I cant seem to figure it out

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it for example by calculating the *Distance* with a *Vector Math* node  of the empty to the points and use *Delete Geometry* to delete all points that are below a certain value.

To check if they are within the distance, you could use a *Math* node set to *Less Than* and either enter a value to decide how far you want the effect to reach out and delete points or - as I did it here - use the *Scale* of the empty (if you don't change the default size of 1 m in the *Object Data Properties* and only use the scale to vary the size). This way the visual reference of the sphere corresponds with the radius of the deleted points.

[image: geometry nodes setup]